# Determining the probability distribution of Y.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

1.) There are two urns. Into **each** urn is placed a set of four balls numbered, 1,2,3, and 4. A ball is randomly selected from each urn.

a.) Give the probability distribution of Y, the *largest* of the numbers on the two balls.

I just can't seem to get my head wrapped around this question. A nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$Y=1$ for the drawing $11$.

$Y=2$ for the three drawings $12,22,21$.

$Y=3$ for the five drawings $13,23,33,32,31$.

$Y=4$ for the seven drawings $14,24,34,44,43,42,41$.

Every drawing has probability $\dfrac1{16}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the numbers on the balls selected from urns $1$ and $2$, respectively, and let $Y=X_1\vee X_2$. There are $16$ possible values of $(X_1,X_2)$, each of them with equal probability $\frac1{16}$. Enumerating these we find that
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y=1) &= \frac1{16}\\
\mathbb P(Y=2) &= \frac3{16}\\
\mathbb P(Y=3) &= \frac5{16}\\
\mathbb P(Y=4) &= \frac7{16}.\\
\end{align}

Comment: Sorry messed up my  last comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So for like P(Y=4) = 7/16 does this mean that 4 has 7/16 probability of being the largest number of the two balls chosen?

Comment: Yes, and that corresponds to the outcomes $$(1,4), (2,4), (3,4), (4,4), (4,1), (4,2), (4,3). $$